How to apply a concept to a member function in a concept?
Assume the following C++ concept
template <typename T>
concept has_set = requires(T t, std::string s) {
    { t.set(s) } -> std::same_as<void>; };
};

I cannot use a concept for parameter s, e.g.
template <typename T>
concept has_set = requires(T t, std::convertible_to<std::string_view> s) {
    { t.set(s) } -> std::same_as<void>; };
};

will fail to compile. Is there any workaround or trick which can be applied here to achieve precisely that goal ?

Note:
This question has a follow-up one here:
How to apply a concept to a member function in a concept and then use it?.
The follow-up question adds a requirement that the usage of the concept should be possible without specifying the concept template arguments explicitly.

"Is there any workaround or trick which can be applied here to achieve precisely that goal" - You haven't really specified a goal, only an attempt at acheiving it which may intself be moot. Why do you think it is important to know that any type that is implicitly and explicitly convertible to string_view may be passed? In constraint checks implementations don't matter, only immediate expressions and their constraints. So why not check a dummy type with the needed convertibility?

I rolled back your edit because you should not edit the question in a way that invalidates exisiting answer(s). Plrease post a new question instead.

In this case you can add another template parameter to the concept, and require it to be convertible to std::string_view:
#include <type_traits>
#include <string_view>

template <typename T, typename S>
concept has_set = requires(T t, S s) {
    requires std::convertible_to<S, std::string_view>;
    { t.set(s) } -> std::same_as<void>;
};

Live demo (with usage example)

How do I apply this to a function that uses the concept? Like e.g. std::string use(has_set auto & f) { /* ... * } does not compile.

The compiler warns me about a missing requires and proposes requires std::convertible_to<S, std::string_view>;

I added a live demo, and also fixed the compiler warning for the missing requires.

This is nearly what I wanted, except I do not want to name the parameter type when explicitly defining the use function. See additional edits and the link to the live demo.

@MarkusW. I rolled back your edit because you should not edit the question in a way that invalidates exisiting answer(s). Plrease post a new question instead.

I can not see how the answer is valid without it being possible to be applied.

Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79130759/how-to-apply-a-concept-to-a-member-function-in-a-concept-and-then-use-it

@MarkusW. but I showed in the demo how it can be applied ... anyway thanks for accepting, and I will have a look a bit later on the new question and try to help you there if I can.

you can use a helper function template instead of trying to directly use std::convertible_to in the concept
example :

Create a helper function that takes a parameter of a generic type and checks if it can be passed to the set method of T
The helper function can utilize concepts to check for convertibility.

template <typename T, typename S>
constexpr auto can_set(T t, S s) 
    -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<decltype(t.set(s)), void>, bool> {
    return true;
}

// Define the has_set concept
template <typename T>
concept has_set = requires(T t) {
    // check if still can call the set method with a std::string_view
    { can_set(t, std::declval<std::string_view>()) } -> std::same_as<bool>;
};```



That is the inverse of what I ask for.
