How to apply a concept to a member function in a concept and then use it?
Follow-up question to this question, where single argument use was not solved.
Assume the following C++ concept:
template <typename T>
concept has_set = requires(T t, std::string s) {
    { t.set(s) } -> std::same_as<void>; };
};

I cannot use a concept for parameter s, e.g.
template <typename T>
concept has_set = requires(T t, std::convertible_to<std::string_view> s) {
    { t.set(s) } -> std::same_as<void>; };
};

will fail to compile. Is there any workaround or trick which can be applied here to let the following additional code compile?
std::string use(has_set auto & f) { /* ... use f.set(...) ... */ }

Please note that part of the solution is already given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/79130496/1528210

I might have managed to solve this updated issue by giving the concept second parameter a default value. Can you check this demo to see if that's what you need ?

I was more into https://godbolt.org/z/7xfMeE9xc

but give me minute to experiment, I might accept your solution.

@wohlstad I will accept your answer since it works for other cases: https://godbolt.org/z/MK9Mv3fn6

Posted my solution as an answer then.

I'm offering an alternative answer, because I think the accepted one will work for most real cases, but isn't a 100% match to my understanding of the requirements.
My understanding of the requirements is: type Foo should match has_set<Foo>, if and only if it has a set method returning void, which can be called with any argument implicitly convertible to string_view. Basically, any valid set implementation should look like: void set(std::string_view).
The best solution I could come up with
#include <concepts>
#include <string_view>


template<typename T>
concept has_set = requires {
    // Use the static cast to support classes that have multiple set overloads
    { static_cast<void(T::*)(std::string_view)>(&T::set) };
};

struct Foo {};
static_assert(!has_set<Foo>);

struct Bar {
    void set(std::string_view);
};
static_assert(has_set<Bar>);

struct Baz {
    void set(std::string);
};
static_assert(!has_set<Baz>);

struct FooBarBaz {
    void set(std::string_view);
    void set(int);
};
static_assert(has_set<FooBarBaz>);

This matches the exact signature you'd like to see for set (see godbolt). Thanks to StoryTeller - Unslander Monica in the comments for suggesting the cast to deal with overload sets.
First attempt
template<typename T>
concept has_set = requires(T t, std::string_view sv) {
    { t.set(sv) } -> std::same_as<void>;
};

This is easy, but not entirely correct. See:
struct Foo {
    Foo(std::string_view) {}
};
struct Bar {
    void set(Foo) {}
};
static_assert(has_set<Bar>, "True, because Bar::set can be called with a string view");
static_assert(requires(Bar b, std::string s) { b.set(s); }, "Fails, because string -> string_view -> Foo is more than one implicit conversion");

This is clearly unexpected. I'd argue that in practice this is still good enough, because I can't imagine when this problem would come up.
Second attempt
namespace detail {
struct StringViewConvertible {
    operator std::string_view();
};
}
template<typename T>
concept has_set = requires(T t, detail::StringViewConvertible svc) {
    { t.set(svc) } -> std::same_as<void>;
};


Since the type is in the detail namespace, the only way someone writes a function accepting this type is if they maliciously want to make your concept fail. I can't think of a way to guard against that.

See the comments of this answer for a neat solution to this!


Since the only thing this type can do is convert to a string_view, the only way the call can be well formed is if T::set accepts a string_view.


You might use lambda which returns local type to avoid namesapce detail Demo

Looks better than my answer. +1.

@Jarod42 thanks for that, it makes that alternative completely safe as far as I can tell. Also, thank you wohlstad, I appreciate it :)

string -> string_view is not implicit. But other than that, the second attempt is what I thought the OP would really want.

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I know. Did I rely on that anywhere without noticing?

The second static assert explanation.

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica the second static assert relies on string to string_view to Foo implicit conversions. No conversion from string_view to string there.

Another point worth mentioing is that T::set could name an overload set, in which case it would be ill-formed to form a pointer to member without a target type. Check instead that static_cast<void(T::*)(std::string_view)>(&T::set) is well-formed may be more robust.

@Wutz - "No conversion from string_view to string here", I didn't mention string_view -> string, I quoeted string -> string_view, and that too is an explicit conversion. So there is no ics here that can be too long. The static assert fails for a different reason that what the string says.

Or NVM. I was certain that is explicit too. It's indeed an implicit conversion. Forgot that footgun.

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica about your first comment: I think "callable with any type convertible to string_view" is equivalent to "takes a string_view as parameter". At least I could not come up with a scenario where one does not equal the other. So I think the second attempt and the one I labeled as best attempt should do the same, but one is more readable to me.

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica right, I knew string to string_view was implicit, which is why I apparently didn't read your comment correctly and just decided you must be talking about string_view to string. About the overload set: you're right, this could even be a valid argument for why the second attempt could be better after all. I'll edit the answer later when I'm not on my phone.

You are right on the money if sane code is involved as far as just checking string_view itself. The difference is usually in mostly-pathologocal cases like an overload set that is set(std::string_view s) = delete; set(auto otherThingConveribleToStrView); - It would produce different results. But I consider supporting such nonsense to be a value judgment, so I wouldn't throw away your best solution on account of that.

Oh, wow! That solution rocks. I went with this here as not a good alternative: https://godbolt.org/z/xb8bb54r1

I voted too fast. Why is static_assert(!has_set<Baz>);? The std::string is convertible to std::stringview and would be a valid implementation, right?

@MarkusW. "I voted too fast." - what you did is actually called "accept", not "vote". You can accept one answer, but in addition you can actually vote any useful answer (including the accepted one), as voting and accepting is separate. See: What should I do when someone answers my question?.

Currently, my solution fails on FooBarBaz, while yours should support static_assert(has_set<Baz>);since std::string is convertible to std::string_view. Do I create a third question?

I am back to @wohlstad 's solution, which I don't like, and I do not understand why the default parameter is evaluated: https://godbolt.org/z/zzGMc4vYx
template <typename T, typename S = std::string> concept has_set = std::convertible_to<S, std::string_view> && requires(T t, S s) { { t.set(s) } -> std::same_as<void>; };

@MarkusW. static_assert(!has_set<Baz>); should hold, because Baz::set is not callable with a string_view. IE Baz{}.set(std::string_view{"abc"}) will not compile. Your question sounds like you want something that's callable with any type convertible to string_view. That's what you get in my answer. You can change it so you accept std::string as parameter, but then you can't call it with types convertible to string_view. Either I misunderstood your requirements, or you yourself are a bit unclear on them. If you want help, you need to make clear what exactly you're looking for.

@Wutz Hmm. You are right that my requirements are unclear—again (sigh). I was unaware that the std::string constructor for StringViewLike is explicit, and I may have wanted something not described by convertible but simply by: template<typename T> concept has_set = requires {  { static_cast<void(T::*)(std::string_view)>(&T::set) }; } || requires {  { static_cast<void(T::*)(std::string)>(&T::set) }; };. I propose you add this additional information to your answer as alternative.

Stackoverflow should allow the marking of several answers as solutions. In this case, the answer from @wohlstad might also be a good fit. Sorry for the back and forth. I learned many things this time, and I have to think about the weird behavior of the default parameter in https://stackoverflow.com/a/79130967/1528210

@MarkusW. voting is the main mechanism for marking answers as useful, and you (as well as anybody else) can upvote as many as you see fit. You can see accepting as an additional feature - a bonus for the answer that suits you the best (this holds even if there is only one answer).

This is an adaptation of the answer from the question that was followed-up here (How to apply a concept to a member function in a concept?):
Similarly to the other case, you can add another template parameter to the concept, and require it to be convertible to std::string_view.
In order to allow to use it as you specified (without supplying the additional template argument), the second template parameter has a default value of std::string:
#include <type_traits>
#include <string_view>
#include <string>

//-------------------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvv-
template <typename T, typename S = std::string>
concept has_set = requires(T t, S s) {
    requires std::convertible_to<S, std::string_view>;
    { t.set(s) } -> std::same_as<void>;
};

Usage example:
struct HasSetClass
{
    void set([[maybe_unused]] std::string const & s) {}
};

void use(has_set auto & o)
{
     o.set("aaa");
}

int main() {
    HasSetClass a;
    use(a);
}

Live demo

This is quite elegant and solves the overloading issues with const and noexcept which kills any traits-related version of this. Kudos!

@wohlstad This doesn't seem to 100% match the expectation from the question. My interpretation is that the asker wants to make sure that there's a set function which takes any argument that is convertible to a string_view. This concept only validates that set is callable with a particular argument type (string by default) and that that argument type is convertible to string_view. If I implement void set(const std::string&);, then the concept will match, yet calling set(string_view{"foo"}) will fail.

@MarkusW.: Not sure of what you want exactly, with above void use(has_set auto & o) is void use(has_set<std::string> auto & o) so a class having set(const char*) won't be accepted Demo.

@Wutz, Jarod42 I see your point. I was indeed not sure about my solution and so posted it initially as a suggestion comment (see below the question).

@MarkusW. please see the comments above. You should consider to un-accept my answer if they indeed relate to what you are looking for. See also the other answer by Wutz.

Your solution is the only one that fulfills all requirements (see https://godbolt.org/z/4bxKcq54Y). I am about to re-accept yours, but the necessity for an evaluated default parameter makes me unhappy.

I switched back again, sorry. See comments above.
